# cloud-init on azure without opening ssh port as `custom_data` in Terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-virtual-machine, cloud-init

I want to pass the `cloud-init.yaml` file, as `custom_data` in Terraform to create a new virtual machine on Azure and install some packages on it. Is it possible to do it without opening ssh port for VM?

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "my-test-server" {
  name                = "my-test-server"
  location            = "centralus"
  resource_group_name = "IAP-MGMT-RESOURCE-GRP"

  size                            = "Standard_D2s_v3"
  admin_username                  = "ubuntu"
  admin_password                  = "12341234"
  disable_password_authentication = false
  custom_data                     = filebase64("scripts/cloud-init.yaml")

  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.my_virtualnetwork.id
  ]

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"
  }
```

In the `/var/log/cloud-init.log` I see the following error:

```
ci-info: no authorized SSH keys fingerprints found for user ubuntu.
```

Comment: This should work because the payload delivery does not require a SSH connection. What else is relevant inside the logs?

Comment: When debugging this sort of thing it's helpful to understand how the cloud platform is supplying the relevant data ("custom data" in your case) to software inside the VM. I'm not super familiar with Azure but from referring to [Custom data and Cloud-init](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/custom-data) I infer that linux VMs on Azure rely on [WALinuxAgent](https://github.com/Azure/WALinuxAgent) as the first program to process that information, and that it obtains it via a "virtual DVD" that's attached to the VM and contains an `ovf-env.xml` including the custom data.

Comment: I don't have a ready-to-go answer for you but I hope that additional context is helpful for figuring out what other log files might be interesting to study to learn what's happening here. In particular, we can see from this that the custom data mechanism doesn't rely on any network services such as SSH, and so any messages related to SSH are likely _not_ related to the problem you're seeing.